# Clicked component trigger event on first component when dynamic added

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-component

I have this component

```
<template>
    <div class="row py-2">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <v-checkbox @clicked="changeStatus($event)" :val="checkFont" :key="'checkfont'">
                <span>Activar/Desactivar</span>
            </v-checkbox>
        </div>
        <transition name="fade">
            <div class="col-sm-12" v-if="checkFont == true">
                <div v-for="(type, key) in types">
                    <div class="my-2">
                        <h5 class="text-capitalize">{{ type.label }}</h5>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="my-2">
                        <v-selectpicker :input-name="fieldName(type.label)" :properties="fonts" :has-addon="false" field="family" :notlang="true" @optionselected="getFont($event, key)"></v-selectpicker>
                    </div>
                    <div class="" v-if="type.font !== ''">
                        <div v-for="(v, index) in getVariants(key)" :key="index">
                            <v-checkbox @clicked="setVariant($event, key, v)" :val="variantText(v)" :key="index">
                                <span>{{ variantText(v) }}</span>
                            </v-checkbox>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    const SelectPicker = () => import('../admin/selectpicker')
    const CustomCheckbox = () => import('./customCheckbox')
    export default {
        data : function() {
            return {
                fonts   : [{family : ''}],
                types   : {
                    headers : {
                        label   : 'Titulos',
                        font : '',
                        variant : ''
                    },
                    paragraphs : {
                        label   : 'parrafos',
                        font    : '',
                        variant : '',
                    },
                    links      : {
                        label   : 'Links',
                        font    : '',
                        variant : '',
                    }
                },
                checkFont : false
            }
        },
        created : function() {
            this.getFonts();
        },
        components : {
            'v-selectpicker' : SelectPicker,
            'v-checkbox' : CustomCheckbox
        },
        methods : {
            getFonts : function() {
                axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?sort=popularity&key=AIzaSyBUjWSsTwBeOFXwHYga8YQZIDauLiS8Gy8').then((response) => {
                    this.fonts = response.data.items;
                });
            },
            fieldName : function(field) {
                return field.toLowerCase()
            },
            getFont : function($event, key) {
                this.types[key].font = $event.option;
                this.getVariants(key);
            },
            changeStatus : function($event) {
                console.log($event)
                this.checkFont   = !this.checkFont;
            },
            getVariants : function(key) {
                return this.fonts.filter((element) => element.family == this.types[key].font)[0].variants;
            },
            setVariant : function($event, key, v) {
                console.log('variant clicked');
                console.log($event);
                this.types[key].variant = v;
            },
            variantText : function(v) {
                return v.indexOf('00') !== -1 ? v.split('00').join('00 ') : v;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the v-checkbox component.

```
<template>
    <div class="cntr">
        <label for="cbx" class="label-cbx">
            <input id="cbx" type="checkbox" :model="val" class="invisible" @change="checked = checkCheckbox(checked)" :checked="checked">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                    <path d="M3,1 L17,1 L17,1 C18.1045695,1 19,1.8954305 19,3 L19,17 L19,17 C19,18.1045695 18.1045695,19 17,19 L3,19 L3,19 C1.8954305,19 1,18.1045695 1,17 L1,3 L1,3 C1,1.8954305 1.8954305,1 3,1 Z"></path>
                    <polyline points="4 11 8 15 16 6"></polyline>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <slot></slot>
        </label>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props : ['val'],
        data : function() {
            let data = {
                checked : false
            };
            return data
        },
        methods : {
            checkCheckbox : function(checkbox) {
                this.$emit('clicked', {
                    value : this.val
                });
                let status = eval(checkbox) == true ? false : true;
                return status;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is in the v-checkbox, everythin work until i click one of the dynamic v-checkbox in the `v-for="(v, index) in getVariants(key)" :key="index"` whenever i click one of these, `the v-checkbox :key="'checkfont'"` its triggered, so the `checkFont` prop value changes

i am checking the component with the vue devtools, and i can see that the `:val` prop have the right value, but when clicked the event emit a boolean and then `@clicked="changeStatus($event)"` is triggered, why this happens? can't i use the component like this? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I realize the problem was the `id` of the `checkbox`, every `checkbox` had the id `cbx` so it was calling always the first element on click